# UML class diagram

Tags: java, uml, class-diagram

I have a main class in java which has no attributes and methods. It only contains a main method which calls methods of other classes.
How can I show this class in a UML class diagram?

Answer (score 2):

You should use **Association** to show this relationship. Association is shown by just connecting two class with a straight line.

If you also want to show the direction of association then you can use directed arrow.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should question whether you need that class. It doesn't sound like it is performing as an object, instead its a superclass with no meaning within an OO context (ie: it has no meaning within your subject matter, holds no state and performs no actions aside from the main method).

Nothing necessarily wrong with that, but its not considered good practise. I would consider merging that main method into another class that has a meaning within your application.